# What would be the fastest way to read integers from a file in Java?

Tags: java, performance, io

I have a file of integers arranged like this:

```
1 2 3 55 22 11 (and so on)
```

And I want to read in these numbers as fast as possible to lessen the total execution time of my program. So far, I am using a scanner with good results. However, I get the feeling that there exists a faster IO utility I can use. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

So yes, I verified that it is the IO in my program that's taking the most time by setting up different timers around the java code and comparing results.

Comment: Why do you need the "fastest" way if you're already getting "good results"? Is your program taking very long to execute?

Comment: Before you jump into optimization, I'd recommend that you use a profiler (such as YourKit) to establish that this part of the code is indeed the overall bottleneck. If it isn't, you'll be wasting your time optimizing it.

Comment: Are those values typical? Always positive, always in the range of bytes, and always below 100? Will they be used as bytes, shorts, ints or longs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Current file format**

If the numbers are represented as `Strings` there is no faster way to read them in and parse them, disk I/O is going to be orders of magnitude slower than anything the CPU is doing. The only thing can do is use a `BufferedReader` with a huge buffer size and try and get as much if not all the file in the memory before using `Scanner`.

**Alternate file format**

If you can represent them as binary in the file and read the numbers in using the `DataInputStream` [class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), then you might get a small decrease in I/O time and a marginal CPU decrease because you don't need to parse the `String` representation into an `int` that probably would not be measurable unless your input file in in hundreds of megabytes or larger. **Buffering the input stream will still have more effect than anything else, use a `BufferedInputStream` in this case.

**How to optimize**

You need robust profiling to even detect if any changes you make are impacting performance **positively** or **negatively**.

Things like OS disk caching will skew benchmarks if you read the same file in over and over, the OS will cache it and screw up your benchmarks. Learn what **good enough** is sooner than later.

> "We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the
>   time: **premature optimization** is the
>   root of all evil" - [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

The **premature** part of Kunth's quote is the important part, it means:

**Don't optimize without profiling and benchmarks to verify that what you are changing is actually a bottleneck and that you can measure the positve or negative impact of your changes.**

[Here is a quick benchmark](https://gist.github.com/989538) comparing a `BufferedInputStream` reading the same set of binary numbers versus a `Scanner` backed by a `BufferedReader` reading the same set of numbers as text representations with a `SPACE` delimiter.

the results are pretty consistent:

For 1,000 numbers on my Core i3 laptop with 8GB of RAM

```
Read binary file in 0001 ms
Read text file in   0041 ms
```

For 1,000,000 numbers on my Core i3 laptop with 8GB of RAM

```
Read binary file in 0603 ms
Read text file in   1509 ms
```

For 50,000,000 numbers on my Core i3 laptop with 8GB of RAM

```
Read binary file in 29020 ms
Read text file in   70346 ms
```

File sizes for the 50,000,000 numbers were as follows:

```
 48M input.dat
419M input.txt
```

Reading the binary is much faster until the set of numbers grows very large. I/O on binary encoded ints is less ( by about 10 times ), there is no `String` parsing logic, and other overhead of object creation and whatever else that `Scanner` does. I went ahead and used the `Buffered` versions of the `InputStream` and `Reader` classes because those are best practices and should be used whenever possible.

For extra credit, compression would reduce the I/O wait even more on the large files with almost no measurable effect on the CPU time.

Comment: actually, I don't think that this problem is IO bound. I've just run a small test, scanning a 37,000,000 char string (about 70MB assuming 2-byte chars, where I'd expect IO to take about a second since it's a pure sequential read) containing positive random numbers < 10,000. it took about 10s to scan it (hence 10 times what I'd expect from a standard hard disk). See test program: https://gist.github.com/989397 While it's certainly possible to tweak some params, it's pretty obvious that this problem is not IO bound. (If you spot problems with my test, please let me know)

Comment: Waffles sample numbers are all less than 100, so a number plus a delimiter use 3 bytes. Numbers less than 100 fit perfectly into a single byte, but they always fit into a byte? Are the numbers representative at all? Did you use integers for reading, which take 4 bytes in binary? With different assumptions come different measurements. If most numbers are smaller than 100, but all of them shall be used as int, reading them as text would need a smaller file to read.

Comment: how does the string `99` plus a space for a delimiter fit into a "single byte"? it also needs to be parsed into a primitive int representation.

Comment: I just tried this out with 6,000,000 decimal numbers; which are represented in binary as 32-bit integers.
In Java the bottleneck is DEFINITELY the parsing of the ASCII data and NOT file IO.
How do I know that: Because of the representation, the ASCII data is NOT much bigger than the binary data. BUT: Parsing the ASCII data is at least 10 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can read the data as fast as the disk allows.  The best way to read it faster is to make it more compact or get a faster disk.

For the format you are using, I would GZip the files and read the compressed data.  This is a simple way to increase the rate you can read the underlying data.

Answer (score -1):

Escalation possibilities:

- Buy a faster disk.
- Buy an ssd-drive.
- Store the file in a ramdisk.

There is always a tradeoff in gaining more performance/speed. The above methods will cost money, and have to be performed on every host, so if this is a program which is sold to multiple customers, it could be a better option to twiddle at the algorithm, which will save money on every host, the program is run.

If you compress the file, or store binary data, the speed to read is increased, but it will be harder to inspect the data with independent tools. Of course we can not tell how often this might happen.

In most circumstances I would suggest keeping human readable data, and live with a slower program, but of course it depends how much time you lose, how often you lose it, and so on too.

And maybe it is just an excercise, to find out, how fast you can get. But then I like to warn from the habit to always reach for highest performance without considering the tradeoffs and the costs.